# BlockingQueue how to wait until the Queue becomes non empty

Tags: java, blockingqueue

Im implimenting a java game with multiplayer and i have a sender thread to send a messages from a Queue  to another player.
I have read here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html
"A Queue that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty"

which operetions and how to use them , and i know that an infinte loop that always checks if something Queue is what i want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Since there appears to be no out-of-the-box solution to this problem, I had to implement my own.

So, what I do is that my `void block()` method invokes `poll()` and saves the item returned.  Then, every method that obtains an item from the queue first checks if we have a saved item, and if so, returns it and clears it, otherwise it delegates to the underlying java blocking queue.

Luckily I only consume items from a single thread, so I do not have to worry about race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

take() will allow you to wait until an element becomes available in the queue or use poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) to wait until a specified time.